# programmatically detect rendering mode in p5js?

Tags: p5.js

for the p5js rendering engine, if in setup() function I use WEBGL vs P2D, how can I know later in my code what rendering mode I am in? I have wrote generic functions that work across 2D and 3D modes and I want the code to execute in different ways based on the rendering mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably are more straightforward and elegant ways of doing it but, in a pinch, you can read the `drawingContext` of the renderer used and see if it's either an instance of `WebGLRenderingContext` or `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

```js
const webglSketch = p => {
 p.setup = () => {
  p.createCanvas(100, 100, p.WEBGL)
  p.background('red')
  console.log('WEBGL?', p._renderer.drawingContext instanceof WebGLRenderingContext)
  console.log('2D?', p._renderer.drawingContext instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)
 }
}

const twoDSketch = p => {
 p.setup = () => {
  p.createCanvas(100, 100)
  p.background('blue')
  console.log('WEBGL?', p._renderer.drawingContext instanceof WebGLRenderingContext)
  console.log('2D?', p._renderer.drawingContext instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)
 }
}

new p5(webglSketch)
new p5(twoDSketch)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you're not using the instance mode, just check the `_renderer` global object.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a more elegant way. Since the _renderer property isn't documented, there's no guarantee it will be available in future versions, so I think the safest bet is to use the drawingContext as you have described. I'm going to suggest that we add a simple boolean property to indicate if the most recent canvas created is 3D.